# Hairy frayed white stuff around bathroom heater pipe joints: asbestos?

Tags: plumbing, heating, pipe, asbestos

I’m a bit worried about some frayed hairy/stringy material around my heated towel rail in the bathroom, sticking out of the pipe joints. It is white, so doesn’t look like hemp to me, and I’m wondering if it could be some kind of asbestos product used to seal the pipes. Any advice would be appreciated! [image]

Comment: Any idea how old the towel rail is?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a synthetic packing material. I have not seen asbestos it that form.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a thread sealing cord. It should be completely harmless. I believe it is made of PTFE string mostly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.